# Hiding a view with constraints and animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints, uiviewanimation

I have a `UIViewController` which is a custom `TabBarController`. Inside I have a `UIView` which holds `UIViewController` and at the bottom another `UIView` which function as a `TabBar`, I want to hide the `TabBar` with animation and keep the constraints in order. For some reason, every time I try to do it, the view constraints getting all messed up.

The `TabBar` has constant height of 100points.

```
- UIViewController
  - viewContent (UIView, the UIViewController container)
  - viewTabBar (UIView as TabBar)
```

[image]

This is my code:

```
func hideTabBar() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 400) {
        self.contentView.frame.size.height += self.viewTabBar.frame.size.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the best way to do this would be to either make the tabbar height constraint an IBOutlet, or just create it programmatically, and then just change that constraint constant value. Something like this:

```
var tabbarHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tabbarView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .none, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([tabbarHeightConstraint])

// Animating, set new tab bar height to 0
tabbarHeightConstraint.constant = 0

UIView.animate(withDuration: 400) {
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // Or wherever the tabbar view is in
}
```

Now if you want to show the tab bar again, just do the same but set the constant to 100.

Comment: Great solution, don't know why I didn't think about that myself :) Thank you!